# Defining a AWS Glue classifier for GeoJSON files

Tags: amazon-s3, geojson, aws-glue

I am looking for a way of defining a JSON path for the classifier I am using to crawl one goejson file. I read the [Writing custom classifiers documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json) and I could define the following path:

```
$.features[*].properties
```

But I got a table of empty rows, also the crawler could not find the geometry column.

Is there a way of easily converting my geojson into a tabular format?

[my produced table properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iDF4.png)

[Athena query returns empty table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzJqq.png)